# Button in child of rv changes how to test: Android

Tags: android-espresso, android-testing, barista

I have a recyclerView with a bunch of childs. Each child has an ImageButton to mark as favourite. Once you click the fav button, the image changes from a white bookmarck with a gray border to a yellow one. I want to check that, once pressed, the button changes the image.
I'm using [Barista](https://github.com/AdevintaSpain/Barista), but I can't find anything similar in the docu, neither in Espresso itself (both [docu](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso?hl=es-419) and [examples](https://github.com/android/testing-samples)).